# What is the semantic markup for footnote?

Tags: html

Let's say I have a footnote... This is what I have in the printed material but I need to translate it for the web.

-The tuition is 129.99. *
[list of table rows]

[at the bottom of the table]
*The tuition price is set by the governing body of colleges.

What is the correct markup for this?

Comment: Just use an anchor? Like Wikipedia.

Comment: well that was simple, ok i'll take a look at their site.

Comment: Also check out http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#footnotes

Comment: There is no markup defined to mean “footnote”, or anything close to that. Therefore, looking for “semantic” markup means polling opinions on which of the various approaches is “semantic”, i.e. what people choose to call that way for some reason. It is more constructive to ask what is the *practical* way, but this is too broad as such, and the answer depends on the context and on the nature of footnotes as well as the desired functionality (e.g. should footnotes be linked, perhaps two-way).